# ENTRYPOINT Script Variables

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I am looking at assigning variables to an entry point script at runtime. I am working on dockerizing one of our internal applications. In my ENTRYPOINT script I have defined some logic to create a database.php file which will include the DB Username and Password. I'd like to run something similar to the following. How do I define `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` as values read on run time?

`docker run -d --name some-app -e DB_USERNAME=secret_username -e DB_PASSWORD=securepassword`

Comment: That `docker run` command probably does what you want (remember to put all Docker options before the image name); is there a specific problem you’re having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *trick* is to ensure you use the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) of (preferably) `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
FROM busybox

ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello ${DOG}"
```

Then:

```sh
docker build --rm --file="Dockerfile" --tag58944222:latest .
docker run --interactive --tty --env=DOG=Freddie  58944222:latest
```

Returns:

```
Hello Freddie
```

#### Updated

Unclear why this was down-voted.

Hopefully this will help:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello ${DOG}"
```

And:

```
FROM busybox

ENV DOG=Henry

COPY ./test.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./test.sh

ENTRYPOINT ./test.sh
```

Returns the same results as before. The addition of the `ENV Dog=Henry` to the Dockerfile serves to provide default values:

```sh
docker run --interactive --tty 58944222:latest
Hello Henry
docker run --interactive --tty --env=DOG=Freddie 58944222:latest
Hello Freddie
```

Comment: For your second response (test.sh example) are we able to define default values using CMD? In essence I would like to set these values so I can run the image without requiring variables then specify if needed.

Comment: Yes, just add e.g. `ENV DOG=Henry` to the Dockerfile to serve as defaults

Comment: Pleased to hear it!